# If then with two double conditions

Tags: excel

I'm using if then, my conditions are

(1) a1 and a2 should be blank or

(2) b1 and b2 should be blank to make c1 and c2 be equal to "Yes".

can you evaluate if my code is correct? thanks

```
If Range("a1").value = "" and Range("a2").value = "" OR 
Range("b1").value = "" and Range("b2").value = "" then
Range("c1").value = "Yes"
Range("c2").value = "Yes"
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap your two main conditions in parenthesis. This will ensure that your conditions are being evaluated the way you want, plus it will make it much clearer to anyone else viewing the code.

Your final code should look like this:

```
If (Range("a1").value = "" and Range("a2").value = "") OR 
(Range("b1").value = "" and Range("b2").value = "") then
Range("c1").value = "Yes"
Range("c2").value = "Yes"
end if
```

Comment: This is a terrible answer as it stands. You should post the correct code here. Don't make future readers have to "work it out". I will up-vote if you pop in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You just require some extra sets of parentheses I believe:

```
If (Range("A1").Value = "" AND Range("A2").Value = "") OR (Range("B1").Value = "" AND Range("B2").Value = "") Then
        Range("C1").Value = "Yes"
        Range("C2").Value = "Yes"
    end if
```